# Installation Guide for Fedena 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fedena

I am trying to install the fedena 3.0 version in the following gems

```
ruby 1.9.1
rubygem 2.4.1

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
bundler (1.2.1)
declarative_authorization (0.5.1)
hoe (3.12.0)
i18n (0.4.2)
mysql (2.8.1)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.9.6)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
test-unit (1.2.3)
```

But I got following error,how do I fix it

**Error is**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user/fedena# rake db:create
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- spec/rake/spectask
/home/user/fedena/lib/tasks/rspec.rake:22:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/fedena/Rakefile:10:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: `gem install rdoc` should help with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by rake. You should install the correct version with the following command:

```
gem install rake -v 0.8.7
```

That will get you past that error. Remember to uninstall prior versions of rake.

Fedena 3.0 requires additional gems to work correctly. You will receive error messages about the missing gem(s) when trying to start the application.